# After 1 arguments, start of each argument does not equal -*

Tags: bash, shell

After 2 arguments, start of each argument does not equal -*

```
for args in "$@"
do
if [[ ${@: 2} != -* ]]; then 
case "$args" in
   -q)
      if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
          echo "$2"
          shift
       fi
    shift
    ;;
   -w)
      if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
          echo "$2"
          shift
       fi
    shift
    ;;
   -e)
      if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
          echo "$2"
          shift
       fi
    shift
    ;;
esac
else 
    echo "arguments start with '-'"
fi
done
```

Only works with the first argument
`-q s d f g h` correctly

`-q -v -b -n -m -n` and `-q -l j u -y d` wrong

After the first argument, the rest of the arguments must not start with the character '-'

`if [ ! -z "$2" ];` - checks if the argument is empty

Comment: How do you call the script? How do you pass the parameters?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709770/after-2-arguments-start-of-each-argument-does-not-equal), which was closed because it lacks details and clarity. Rather than reposting in another forum, you should go back to the original question, and *add details and clarity*. How exactly are you using this (add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? What do you expect it to do, and how does what it actually does differ from that? And what's the larger purpose (i.e. what are you trying to accomplish)?

Comment: What do you expect the loop to do? You're not using the loop variable `args` within the loop. What exactly do you expect `${@: 3}` to do?

Comment: @ilkkachu I need the condition to be met, but it doesn't work the way I need it!

Comment: @ZerooneX, yes, wanting to check if a condition is met is a reason to use an `if` statement. I wasn't asking about that, I was asking _what_ test you are trying to do with`${@: 3}`. Also, there was this question some comments above this one: _"And what's the larger purpose (i.e. what are you trying to accomplish)?"_

Comment: Please answer the questions people are asking you. They are not asking to be annoying, we need the answers to be able to help you. You still haven't told us how you run the script. You still haven't explained what actually happens (how does it fail?). You haven't told us what you think it is doing either. Your code is clearly not doing what you want it to do, but we cannot know what you want it to do unless you tell us. It is code: by definition it does what it is supposed to do, the problem is what the human expects it to do instead.

Comment: After the first argument, the rest of the arguments must not start with the character '-'

Comment: @ZerooneX, if you want to check that the arguments after then first don't start with a `-`, you'd do something like `first=$1; shift; for arg in "$@"; do if [[ "$arg" == -* ]]; then echo "arg '$arg' starts with a '-'"; exit 1; fi; done`. But that's not nearly what your script seems to be doing. Somehow, I suspect you're trying to reimplement `getopts`, but for some reason you either can't or won't tell that plainly. If you can't explain your goals clearly, it's very hard to help you. After all, anyone other than you knows even less about what you're aiming at.

Comment: Why not just use `getopts`? It's built in to bash and most (all?) other bourne-like shells.   Run `help getopts` in bash for an overview.  Also search for `getopts` here on this site for numerous examples of how to use it.

Comment: Hint: A `for` ... `in` loop does not change the positional parameters, i.e., `$1, $2, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to verify that none of the arguments, except the first, starts with a dash.

You can do this like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 != -* ]]; then
    printf '1st argument, "%s", does not start with a dash\n' "$1"
    exit 1
fi >&2

arg1=$1

shift

for arg do
    if [[ $arg == -* ]]; then
        printf 'Argument "%s" starts with a dash\n' "$arg"
        exit 1
    fi
done >&2

echo 'All arguments ok'

printf 'arg 1 = "%s"\n' "$arg1"
printf 'other arg = "%s"\n' "$@"
```

If you need your 1st argument to be `-q` specifically, change the first test from

```
[[ $1 != -* ]]
```

to

```
[[ $1 != -q ]]
```